# What is extn-utils.html in the chrome developer console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, pageload

When I load a web page with the chrome developer console open, I see jquery loading `extn-utils.html`, and that loads `extn-utils.js`.  What are those?

[image: developer console]

Comment: [Not a Chrome/ium thing](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=extn-utils) so it must be something added by your page or an extension you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It cause no harm. It is mostly by Adobe Acrobat extension. To verify disable it in chrome://extensions and check.